Trouble While Setting CUDA Enviormental variables in ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.15.0
as we install new drivers , their binary updations to system path becomes neccesity
as there is one temporary method to export path via terminal
but when i want to make it permannent i have to set in root/.bashrc,root/.profile & home/.bashrc, home/.profile
after updating a path here as 
export PATH=`$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.8/bin`
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.8/lib64`

in all four files mentioned aboves
the PATH Defination gets updated and basic linux commands like clear and ls also not works
i get to realise it has to be insert in a list/array faishon so i refer this post how-to-multiple-entries-to-path
so i updated PATH in all above four files as
export PATH='/bin:\ /usr/bin:\ /usr/sbin:\ /usr/local/cuda-11.8/bin:\'

but even after this my basic linux commands are working but cuda is not able to detect when i am hitting nvcc -v in terminal  as nvcc location is already at exported as  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.8/bin`
i dont know where i am making mistake please help
to help me which knowldege and awareness i am lacking so i am stuck to this problem

You realize you mention relative directories when you say "* i have to set in root/.bashrc,root/.profile & home/.bashrc, home/.profile*" thus the results may not be identical to having set specific directories; ie /home is not $HOME or /home/$USER.  Have you defined the paths exactly as in your question or something else; as your question shows understanding issues in my opinion  (do note /root/ is a USER directory; what exactly do you mean by "root/" ? as did you mean that root ?

@guiverc 1.root directory as when you login through root terminal you access that particular .bashrc inside root while home also have one copy of .profile &.bashrc so i am setting in both 2. yes their complete absolute  path i have verified into orignal location then i updated 3. i have not set $HOME as one of enviorment variable as i am setting the compelte absolute  path but. but still issue is there

The / directory is root file-system directory which is very different to the root user directory which has the word root in the name.  The word root exists only in directories and NOT the actual / directory itself. Root logins are disabled by default on Ubuntu systems; but if you've used complete or specific directories; please amend your question to say so; as you've written your paths as relative directories (ie. relative to $PWD).  The system sets many variables; including $HOME, $USER, $PWD etc... so you don't need to. ie. try echo $PWD $USER $HOME

the thing is when i do echo $PATH  in terminal it shows me all the binaries path including /bin/:/usr/bin: ...etc but when i update the cuda path in the .bashrc in my home & root directory and i do echo $PATH in terminal it shows me this new path only and earlier path gets removed i don;t know why when i want to add this new entry to system $PATH it eliminates all preceddings entries

No spaces should be added to your PATH. Modify your PATH as recommended by the Nvidia instuctions (put first), in .profile or .bashrc (only one needed, I prefer .profile since the Gnome desktop terminal works as a login terminal). Don't mess with system files like those in /root. Modify your user files in /home/$USER only.

I don't know if the ` is a typo in you description, but actually you should not have it.
export PATH=`$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.8/bin`
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.8/lib64`

should be:
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.8/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.8/lib64

